# What requirements are there to be able to vote in the NZ general election if living abroad?

Tags: new-zealand, elections, new-zealand-citizens

The New Zealand general election is on September 23rd this year.  What are the requirements for a NZ citizen living overseas to be eligible to vote in the NZ election?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sent the same question to "[I Vote NZ](https://www.facebook.com/IvoteNZ/)" (The official NZ Government Elections Facebook page) on facebook a week or two ago.

My question:

> Are we eligible to vote while living outside of NZ?  If so, how do we
>   actually vote?

Their response:

> Yes - as long as you're NZ citizens, over 18, and have been back to NZ
>   within the past 3 years, then you're eligible. You can either download
>   and print voting papers from our website, vote in person at an
>   overseas post, or apply for a postal vote. More information about all
>   these options is here: [Voting from overseas](http://www.elections.org.nz/events/2017-general-election/voting-2017-general-election/voting-overseas)
>
> You're also eligible if you're NZ permanent residents who have been
>   back to NZ in the last 12 months